# Using db.open with MongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two questions.

First, the MongoDB documentation constantly refers to using `db.open()` and then `db.collection()`, but i have noticed that i'm still able to work with the api even without first calling `db.open().` Is it safe to do so? Is the api internally calling `db.open()`?

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection

Second, is there a param in the `db` object that specifies if `db.open()` was called? If not, how else could i find out if `db.open()` was called?

The reasoning is because i have built several functions that communicate with mongo, but when some of the functions interact with each other, i get errors that the database cant be 'opened' multiple times.

**EDIT**

I found this param in the `db` object. It appears this is a bool determining the use of the `db.open()` but im not 100% sure, does anyone know? `db.serverConfig.internalMaster`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you need to know if a db object is connected you can check db._state == 'connected' or db.serverConfig.isConnected().

You are probably better of actually passing in a known connected object to your mvc, ensuring the db is opened before you boot up the application.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also is it okay if i dont call `db.open()` and `db.close()`? Will this happen on its own? It seems that the api still works without calling `db.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

> The reasoning is because i have built several functions that communicate with mongo, but when some of the functions interact with each other, i get errors that the database cant be 'opened' multiple times.

You should reuse the db object instead of opening it multiple times - the same should be done with collection objects as there is a cost associated with creating them.

Comment: Yes, im familiar with both of these statements, but my code is in an mvc type structure. So because of this, in the controller where im actually calling the functions, it knows nothing about `db.open()` and `db.collection()`, all it knows is `doThis()`. This is why i would like to know a way to figure out if `db.open()` was called, so i can properly nest the controllers functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a javascript driver, and it uses an 'openCalled' boolean property directly off the db object.  Referencing it is as simple as

```
if (!db.openCalled) { //open database }
```